# Mongodb: making a "groupBy" inside an aggregation and $project

Tags: mongodb

My first question. Tried to find the answer but couldn't.

I have a dataset like the following:

```
{
    _id: "6294d59455be467837cb6262",
    text: 'Primeiro post',
    image: '15bee21f99c0c879ecee4633f25eaa91',
    width: 327,
    height: 245,
    location: 'Porto Alegre, Rio Grande do Sul',
    poster: { name: 'J R', avatar: 'c633219c7fbacd09db9a9d54986b36b9' },
    reactions: [
      { filename: 'image1', userId: 23 }, 
      { filename: 'image2', userId: 12 }, 
    ]
},
{
    _id: "6294d59455be656589cb62825",
    text: 'Segundo post',
    image: '15bee21f99c0c879ecee4633f25423sgf',
    width: 327,
    height: 245,
    location: 'Porto Alegre, Rio Grande do Sul',
    poster: { name: 'J R', avatar: 'c633219c7fbacd09db9a9d54986b36b9' },
    reactions: [
      { filename: 'image3', userId: 23 }, 
      { filename: 'image2', userId: 12 }, 
      { filename: 'image2', userId: 56 }, 
      { filename: 'image7', userId: 9 }, 
    ]
},
...
```

I want to retrieve all the fields, along with 2 things:

- if the userId passed to the query is on the userId of the array 'reactions' - that's done in the *reactionsByMe* field I created with a $filter (query below);
- group by 'filename' with the quantity on each of the registers that are returned;

I have the following working **aggregate** query:

```
[
    { $match: { 'createdBy.companyId': req.userInfo.companyId, type: 'post' } },
    {
      $project: {
        reactionsByMe: {
          $filter: {
            input: '$reactions',
            as: 'reaction',
            cond: { $eq: ['$$reaction.userId', req.userInfo.userId] }
          },
        },
        text: 1,
        image: 1,
        width: 1,
        height: 1,
        location: 1,
        poster: 1,
      }
    },
]
```

I just don't know how to make a group inside the $project.

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Edit: the expected output:

```
{
    _id: "6294d59455be467837cb6262",
    text: 'Primeiro post',
    image: '15bee21f99c0c879ecee4633f25eaa91',
    width: 327,
    height: 245,
    location: 'Porto Alegre, Rio Grande do Sul',
    poster: { name: 'J R', avatar: 'c633219c7fbacd09db9a9d54986b36b9' },
    reactions: [
      { _id: 'image1', count: 3 },
      { _id: 'image2', count: 5 },
    ]
}
```

With the "reactions" property giving me the total of each image in each document

Comment: can you add the expected output also in text json? Also we dont see the field `createdBy`. If you are still trying to fix it, i think you need `$unwind` first and then `$group`, you cant group an array.

Comment: Hi @Takis. About the createdBy, I accidentally ommited that field, you can ignore it.